# access list values with index python

Tags: string, list, split, concatenation, python-3.8

So, I encountered something really interesting. I splitted a string with .splitlines().
When I print that list, it works just fine and outputs values in that form: ['Freitag 24.11', '08:00'].
But if I try to access any values of that list by an index, e.g. list[0], it should give me the first value of that list. In this case 'Freitag 24.11'.

```
splittedParameters = tag.text.splitlines()
print(splittedParameters[0])
```

So as explained, if I dont use the index [0] it just works fine and outputs the whole list. But in that form with the index it says: "IndexError: list index out of range"

the whole code:

```
    from requests_html import HTMLSession

    startDate = None
    endDate = None
    summary = None
    date = ''
    splittedDate = ''

    url = 'ANY_URL'

    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render()

    aTags = r.html.find("a.ui-link")

    for tag in aTags:
        splittedParameters = tag.text.splitlines()
        print(splittedParameters[0])
```

Comment: does ```splittedParameters``` = ['Freitag 24.11', '08:00']

Comment: could you show us what ```tag.text.splitlines()``` looks like in real code please

Comment: please ecxplain what tag.text containing

Comment: You should have a typo somewhere, I was unable to reproduce your problem. I sugest you to make a test in isolation, like this: https://repl.it/@alejomongua/IndigoFreeExam

Comment: tag.text contains a string looking like: 'Montag 23.11\n09:10'

Comment: @coderoftheday yes it does

Comment: what's the package for HTMLSession()? the code wont run

Comment: ```NameError: name 'HTMLSession' is not defined
```

Comment: its requests_html

Answer (score 0):

```
splittedParameters
```

is returning nothing, as in its given no value.

there's no text in `aTags`

```
print(aTags)

>>> [<Element 'a' class=('logo', 'ui-link') href='index.php'>]
```

After reading your comment I tried:

```
for tag in aTags:
    print(tag.text)
    splittedParameters = tag.text.splitlines()
```

I got nothing printed

Comment: Did you see the picture i uploaded? Why the heck does it not work?

Comment: can you either copy the code into the question, or show me what ```splittedParameters ``` looks like in real code, as in paste it in

Comment: or do ```print(type(splittedParameters))``` and show me what you get

Comment: it says <class 'list'>

Comment: but in the for loop i iterate through the aTags and in each tag there is the attribute text, which is a string and i can also print out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224757/discussion-between-lion-hunter-and-coderoftheday).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
The problem was that in the first run of the for loop the list "splittedParameters" empty is.

```
    if len(splittedParameters) > 0:
        print(splittedParameters[0])
```

this will work.